# DownloadFileCompleted/DownloadProgressChanged events do not work

Tags: c#, events, webclient

I have a background worker (as seen below) with DownloadFileCompleted/DownloadProgressChanged events. After several hours of testing and a lot of research, I couldn't get it to work. The file downloads successfully but the events don't run. I looked at a lot of documentation pages and searched for this issue here, but they don't seem to match my case... Would appreciate if someone could help me out on this one!

```
    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler (webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler  (webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);

            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(myUri), path);

        }
    }

    void webClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object s, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Download completed!");
    }
    void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object s, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be something else wrong with your code as running effectively that same code, it works fine.

Are you sure your program is simply not finished and closing before the work is done as a BackgroundWorker won't keep your application alive.

Here is my example, with a foreground Thread to keep the application alive until done

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            new Thread(() =>
            {
                var client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);

                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin"), @"C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\100mb.bin");
            }).Start();
        }

        private static void webClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object s, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Download completed!");
        }
        private static void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object s, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently the problem was the fact that I use a background worker instead of a thread. Switching it to a new thread worked.

Comment: Ok if that is your underlying problem I would review your code more. For example why would the background worker fail? It should work fine. It suggests your code is "ending" or the part of code holding the reference ot the callback functions is getting cleaned up/disposed before the background worker. I would suggest using a Task.Run(() => { /* your code here */ }); over a Thread (which should re-introduce the same issue, as it uses background threads), however I still think you should review your code first to understand why.